# Error "SSL Provider: The target principal name is incorrect." when try to connect to SQL Server from ODBC18 in ssl mode

Tags: sql-server, ssl-certificate, odbc

I have tried to connect to Microsoft SQL Server in SSL mode from ODBC Driver for SQLServer 18 version.

For that, I have created self-service and rootCA certificates and deployed them in both SQL Server and client machines. When trying to connect, getting the error -

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The target principal name is incorrect.
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish a connection
```

Can suggest what went wrong and how could I fix this issue?

Please point us to any references on how to create SSL certificates.

Comment: Self-certified certificate is unlikely to be trusted, why do you think it would be? Use a  proper certificate purchsaed from a public CA, or from your private CA. For purely development purposes you could do `TrustServerCertificate=true`

Comment: The server name (or IP address) in the connection string needs to be one of the Subject or SubjectAltNames in the server certificate. If you're using the `New-SelfSignedCertificate` PowerShell script to create self-signed certs this means the `-Subject` and `-DnsName` parameters. How did you deploy it to the server? Did you use SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager to bind the certificate to the SQL Server instance? And restart it?